# Boto3 Update Cloudwatch alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I have stored alarm object as variable:
`alarm = cloudwatch.Alarm(AlarmName)`
Then I modified the one attribute of the alarm variable and I wanted send this update to AWS.
I tried method `alarm.load()` or `alarm.reload()` but these pull the data from AWS and overwrite my local variable.

Also, I tried to use cloudwatch resource and method `put_metric_alarm`, but it does not accept as the argument Alarm object:
AttributeError: 'cloudwatch.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'put_metric_alarm'

Is there any way to push local Alarm definition do AWS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`put_metric_alarm` is used to both create and **update** CloudWatch alarms. An example of how to push local alarm definition to AWS using boto3 is here

```
import boto3

# Create CloudWatch client
cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

# CloudWatch Resource
cwres = boto3.resource('cloudwatch')

# Get Alarm Configuration
alarm = cwres.Alarm('My Alarm')

# Update alarm copying all attributes from local alarm variable
cloudwatch.put_metric_alarm(
    AlarmName=alarm.name,
    ComparisonOperator=alarm.comparison_operator,
    EvaluationPeriods=alarm.evaluation_periods,
    MetricName=alarm.metric_name,
    Namespace=alarm.namespace,
    Period=120,                    # changed attribute
    Statistic=alarm.statistic,
    Threshold=alarm.threshold,
    ActionsEnabled=alarm.actions_enabled,
    AlarmDescription=alarm.alarm_description,
    Dimensions=alarm.dimensions,
    Unit=alarm.unit
)
```

And as we see here in the History tab, "My Alarm" was updated.

[image: Alarm History Tab]

This is a long way of copying all attributes, since it seems like API does not accept local alarm object.